# Python: Where to put the function, which is only used once inside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, coding-style

I noticed that the function A is only used once in function B. They both belong to the same class.
If the function A will only be used inside the function B once.

Where should I put it? Would one option be faster than the other?

#### Option 1:

write the function A inside the function B.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def func_B(self):
        def func_A():
            print('a')
        
        func_A()
```

#### Option 2:

write function A as a class function, at the same level with B.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func_A(self):
        print('a')
     
    def func_B(self):
        self.func_A()
```

Comment: This is strictly opinion-based. You can put your function anywhere you like, really. Whether you want it to be visible as a class member or not is purely for you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on what `func A` is doing and if at a point it'll be needed outside `func B`. Personally, I'd want to put it as a method in the class outside `func B`(Option 2) for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

It's option 1 but option 2 would work in this case too. Using option 2 makes func_A() callable anyway within the class since its in the class's scope, but if you're sure that isn't necessary, you can just do option 1.

Comment: You know, they have same "coding" costs. Does option 1 has any other advantages?

Comment: @zheyuanWang I'm not sure what a "coding" cost is, but technically you could have another function that's named func_A inside the class within option 1 (Really bad idea and practice), in that case you can only use option 1

Answer (score 1):

If the function `func_A()` is only called by `func_B()` and not called by any other function or through Class object, I'd recommend to not create `func_A()` and write Body of `func_A()` inside `func_B()`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
#    def func_A(self):
#        print('a')
     
    def func_B(self):
        print('a')
```